# Why this code returns a zero-length "BufferedReader"?

Tags: java

This code was pasted from a tutorial web site and does not works in my machine (win7-amd64)! By the way, I would like to run this code to obtain the creation date/time of a common file.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("cmd /c dir c:\\logfile.log /tc");
BufferedReader br =
   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String data = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   data = br.readLine();
}
System.out.println("Extracted value : " + data);
//split by space
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data);
String date = st.nextToken();//Get date
String time = st.nextToken();//Get time
System.out.println("Creation Date  : " + date);
System.out.println("Creation Time  : " + time);
```

Comment: Do you have a file "logfile.log" in the drive "C:" ?

Comment: What is the contents of the file?

Comment: Add information on your problem and a StackTrace.

Comment: Why don't you use java `File` class to read access the same information from java code.

Comment: That code works for me, with a class which exists...

Comment: Are you attempting to get the file's creation date/time, or are you attempting to read a date and time from the file?

Comment: The code actually works fine for me too. Can you define what "does not work" means, precisely?

Comment: I think the OP should run a `cmd /c dir C:\logfile.log /tc` in the command line and copy/paste the result in his question.

Comment: Yes, the file exists and it is a common 'text file'. The problem is that 'readLine' call always returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to run this code to obtain the creation date/time of a common file.

If you can use Java 7, the creation date is available via [`Files.readAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) and [`BasicFileAttributes.creationTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#creationTime%28%29)

Comment: Thanks all of you. Solved with the ColinD and Mike hot tips!

Answer (score 0):

The file `logfile.log` doesn't exist and the `BufferedReader` read exactly 4 lines. A the 5th attempt it returns null. So `data` is null.

Comment: Thanks all of you. Solved with the ColinD and Mike hot tips!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the command:

```
dir c:\\logfile.log /tc
```

returns more lines than just the lines you want!
Try open a CMD an exec that command by your own. You'll see something like that:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of C:\

22/02/2013  12:00              XXXX logfile.log
               1 File(s)          XXXX bytes
               0 Dir(s)  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX bytes free
```

So you'll need to ignore the firsts lines.
What I suggest you to do is to use a reader that you'll be able to use the readLine() method and filter to just use the line that contains the file name on it.